# Android Studio/LibGDX: Is it possible to press two buttons with a single touch?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm making a fighting game for android using Android Studio and LibGdx. It'd be really cool if I could have attack input combos like Light+Medium. I seem to be able to register multiple inputs if touched by multiple digits. But what if I wanted to use my thumb to press two buttons at once? Is it possible?

Edit: This is a touch screen only game. So, ideally the player would press two attack buttons on their screen with their thumb.

Comment: It's not very clear of what touches you are talking about. Are you pressing physical keyboard keys or game controller or touching the screen?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to be vague. I assumed that b/c I mentioned android that the touch screen was implied.

Yes it's touch screen only. So I'm wondering if I can allow a player to press two buttons with one finger. For example, using their thumb in a similar way to how they would press two buttons on a PS4 controller.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: No, it's not possible.

**Detailed answer**: A touch on the screen will always be registered as a point. This means you won't be able to get the width, hight or shape of the touch event, but only the center of it. So you cant realy know whether both buttons are pressed. (I think this behaviour is not specific to libGDX, but to all phone operating systems; at least all that I know).

**Possible Workarround**: You could try to add an invisible button in between two buttons to "emulate" a touch on both buttons, since when pushing both buttons usually the center of the thumb will be the position, that libGDX will get as the resulting touch event.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. Since I did notice that when I laid down my thumb it only "touched" where the tip of my thumb was. Thanks for confirming it. I thought about having hidden buttons in between. That might work. It's something I'll have to test to see how easy it would be to hit them on accident.